# How to get title of UITabBarItem in the More section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method that determines the title of the `UITabBarItem` and does something accordingly. This works well for items in my `UITabBar` but when I click on the More button the rest of my `UITabBarItems` are in a `UITableView`. How can I determine the title in the More section?

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    if ([self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.title isEqualToString:@"All"]) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you select a view controller in your UITabBarController, the method you mention will be called, and most important, **the view controller currently shown will be passed to you as parameter**; you can then use the following code to find the class and title of the controller, including the "more" controller:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
    NSLog(@"controller title: %@", viewController.title);
}
```

In a quick test, just by adding a couple of controllers in Xcode, this is what you get in the console:

```
2011-03-28 09:13:21.795 TabTest[39015:207] controller class: UIViewController
2011-03-28 09:13:21.797 TabTest[39015:207] controller title: (null)
2011-03-28 09:13:23.922 TabTest[39015:207] controller class: UITableViewController
2011-03-28 09:13:23.925 TabTest[39015:207] controller title: (null)
2011-03-28 09:13:24.505 TabTest[39015:207] controller class: UITableViewController
2011-03-28 09:13:24.506 TabTest[39015:207] controller title: (null)
2011-03-28 09:13:24.945 TabTest[39015:207] controller class: UIMoreNavigationController
2011-03-28 09:13:24.945 TabTest[39015:207] controller title: More
```

On the other side, when you select a controller **inside** the "more" list, you won't be notified in your UITabBarControllerDelegate method (weird, IMHO). To help you get notifications when you select controllers in that list, you could do the following:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
    NSLog(@"controller title: %@", viewController.title);

    if (viewController == tabBarController.moreNavigationController)
    {
        tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (navigationController == self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController)
    {
        NSLog(@"more controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
        NSLog(@"more controller title: %@", viewController.title);
    }
}
```

Your class should also implement the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol, of course.

This is the result of a sample run, using the above code and tapping a couple of times in the UITabBar and the "more" list:

```
2011-03-28 09:27:42.496 TabTest[39113:207] controller class: UIViewController
2011-03-28 09:27:42.498 TabTest[39113:207] controller title: (null)
2011-03-28 09:27:44.306 TabTest[39113:207] controller class: UIMoreNavigationController
2011-03-28 09:27:44.307 TabTest[39113:207] controller title: More
2011-03-28 09:27:44.310 TabTest[39113:207] more controller class: UIMoreListController
2011-03-28 09:27:44.311 TabTest[39113:207] more controller title: More
2011-03-28 09:27:45.632 TabTest[39113:207] more controller class: SecondViewController
2011-03-28 09:27:45.634 TabTest[39113:207] more controller title: (null)
2011-03-28 09:27:47.156 TabTest[39113:207] more controller class: UIMoreListController
2011-03-28 09:27:47.156 TabTest[39113:207] more controller title: More
2011-03-28 09:27:48.581 TabTest[39113:207] controller class: UITableViewController
2011-03-28 09:27:48.582 TabTest[39113:207] controller title: (null)
```

Hope this helps!