# ios - UITabItem doesn't work when moreNavigation in TabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, openurl

My app is basically a UITabBarController that **had**  5 tabs... 2 tabs were customized view controllers, two were different webviews, and one invoked the Safari browser application not in a webview, but as an application, due to AppStore constraints.

The way I launched the Safari (for better or worse) was by using shouldSelectViewController in a delegate, which performed the openURL.

Unfortunately, I needed to add a tab today, so this tab moved to the "more..." view. Since it is no longer a tab, shouldSelectViewController no longer works. And since it isn't/can't be a webview, that doesn't work. (The other tab that moved to "more..." was a webview and does still work on an iPhone. All is well on an iPad.)

I haven't been able to get any delegate calls working for the "more..." list items.

Any help? Pointers? Suggestions? Directions? Links?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds more like a design issue than a code issue. You're going to need to put a button somewhere else.

Comment: After a good night's sleep and some more research, I found the information I needed in this post on [didSelectViewController not getting called when in “More” section
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803352/didselectviewcontroller-not-getting-called-when-in-more-section).