# More Tab bar Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar based application, with more than 5 tab bar items - so i get 4 of them directly showing in the view and the rest available by selecting the "More" tab. When a tab bar item is pressed, i want to Open UIAlertView then pressed OK and goes inside it.
So, in the

**- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarCtrl didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController** method,

This works for the tabs visible in the view -that is the 4 first and the "More" tab- but does not work for the rest of my tab bar items which are shown in the list after pressing the "More" tab.

Comment: Plz provide screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

The UITabBarController has a moreNavigationController property. This is in turn a UINavigationController and you can set a delegate on it to capture changing to tabs 5 and beyond.

Comment: I used - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
but it open ViewController... My question is that i do not want to open it. When tab pressed a alert Open , after pressing OK it goes inside.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803352/didselectviewcontroller-not-getting-called-when-in-more-section for detail. Same question?