# In Swift how do I set a delegate by restorationIdentifier in the tabBarController when there are more than 5 tabs?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

For the first four tabs I use the restorationIdentifier to set up the proper delegate for each viewController.  In the case of the 5th and 6th tabs, the restorationIdentifier is *$MoreNavigationController$* because you don't jump directly to the viewController.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't state my question very well so it deserved the down-votes it got.  It took me far longer than I expected but I found the answer: [didSelectViewController not getting called when in "More" section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803352/didselectviewcontroller-not-getting-called-when-in-more-section).

But since that's written in obj-C I thought I'd share the Swift version I wrote.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // If the user hits the "More" tab for the first time, we need to set up tabController as a delegate for More's navigationController
    if (viewController == tabBarController.moreNavigationController && tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate == nil) {
        tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self
    }
    setUpDelegates(viewController)
}

// This is called when the user chooses something from the list from “More”
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    setUpDelegates(viewController)
}

// This manages setting up all view controllers with delegates or whatever when they are selected
func setUpDelegates(viewController: UIViewController) {
    if viewController.restorationIdentifier == “foo” {
        let fooController = viewController as? FooController
        fooController?.delegate = dataManager
    } else if viewController.restorationIdentifier == “bar” {
        let barController = viewController as? BarController
        barController?.delegate = dataManager
    }
}
```