# How to check selected Tab Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

In my project I create TabBarController by Programmatically.

There are 2 Tab bar.(Construction List Tab and Setting Tab)

In Setting Tab when Push to next viewController(ex. ChangePassword) it worked.

But in ChangePassword ViewController when touch on Tab Setting View will change to Setting Tab.(This problem same in every ViewController that push from Setting Tab)

**Requirement**

I don't want to change ViewController from ChangePassword ViewController to Setting ViewController when Touch Tab Setting. How to resolve it?

**Example Code : Main ViewController**

```
- (void) addTabbarController
{
     // construction List
     ConstructionListViewController *constructionListVC = [[ConstructionListViewController alloc] init];
     UINavigationController *constructionListNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:constructionListVC];

     // Setting
     SettingViewController *settingVC = [[SettingViewController alloc] init];
     UINavigationController *settingNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingVC];

     // UITabBar Controller
     UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
     tabController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
     tabController.delegate = self;
     tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:constructionListNVC, settingNVC, nil];
     tabController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
     [tabController setSelectedIndex:0];
     self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:NO];
}
```

**Example Code : Setting ViewController**

```
-(void) touchOnChangePassword:(QButtonElement *) element
{
    ChangePasswordViewController *changePasswordViewController = [[ChangePasswordViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: changePasswordViewController animated:YES];
}

// touchOnPasscodeLock Button
-(void) touchOnPasscodeLock:(QButtonElement *) element
{
    // go to Passcode Lock Screen
}

-(void) touchOnTermAndCondition:(QButtonElement *) element
{
    // go to TermAndCondition Screen
}

-(void) touchOnOpenSourceAttribute:(QButtonElement *) element
{
    // go to OpenSourceAttribute Screen
}
```

**Example Display : Setting ViewController**

[image]

**Example Display : Change Password ViewController**

[image]

Comment: Use tabcontroller.selectedIndex to know which tab is selected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885667/iphone-app-detect-which-tab-bar-item-was-pressed   this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the UITabBarControllerDelegate methods? You've set the delegate but I don't see you implementing the delegate methods. They let you prevent changing tab views selectively.

Comment: i use `-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` for check when tab. it's alway access this delegate method. I have some method use in delegate. My problem can use this delegate? How to resolve it?

Comment: `didSelectViewController` is too late; the view controller was already selected. Why don't you use `shouldSelect`? That's what it's for.