# How to know which row of table on more tab is selected in TabBarController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to know which row user is selecting on the table which appears automatically when we have more tabBar items in TabBarController

Comment: Have you tried some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041982/how-to-get-the-event-that-switch-tab-menu-on-iphone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone app - detect which tab bar item was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885667/iphone-app-detect-which-tab-bar-item-was-pressed)