# How to get the tag of selected UITabBarItem in UITabBarController for more than 5 items?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

In Storyboard I created `UITabBarController` with 6 relationships to another view controllers. So now I have 6 `UITabBarItems`. I tagged them from **0** to **5**. This is why I detect what `UITabBarItem` was selected by user.

**NOTE:**

**I cannot use `selectedIndex` because this way doesn't tell me what tab was chosen, since user IS ABLE to change the order of items in `UITabBar`**.

Within `UITabBar` there is property `items` and `selectedItem` but if there is more than 5 items, the property `items` keeps max **5** items.

For instance when user choose `UITabBarItem` at index **4** OR **5**, selected Index is 4 for both of them. Now the `UITabBarItem` with index **4** indicates on tab bar **"More Items"**.

So, I really need to access to the selected `UITabBarItem` to get its **tag**.Is there any way to do this?

This is my situation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a huge digging, the solution is fairly simple:-)

within your `UITabBarController`'s `delegate` that conforms to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol:

```
//MARK: - UITabBarControllerDelegate

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    if viewController == tabBarController.moreNavigationController {
        tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self
    } else {
        findSelectedTagForTabBarController(tabBarController)
    }
}

//MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    findSelectedTagForTabBarController(navigationController.tabBarController)
}

//MARK: - Private

private func findSelectedTagForTabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController?) {

    if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
        if let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
            let selectedIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
            let selectedController: UIViewController? = viewControllers.count > selectedIndex ? viewControllers[selectedIndex] : nil
            if let tag = selectedController?.tabBarItem.tag {
                //here you can use your tag
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController.view.tag
```

as the UIViewController does not have tag, BUT its view has.

Also, you can you UIViewController's property `restorationIdentifier`

Comment: It doesn't work either. I cannot check `restorationIdentifier` for controllers from `More Items`.

Comment: what about `tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewController objectAtIndex`? It will give you access to viewControllers stored in "More Items".

Comment: How do I get the `index`? Anyway, `moreNavigationController` has only one viewController in `viewControllers`.

Comment: After some search I think I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893776/how-to-get-title-of-uitabbaritem-in-the-more-section). Check the answer and let me know if it helped.

Comment: No, because in my case my 6 `UITabBarItems` lead to 6 different `UINavigationControllers`. Every `UINavigationController` has relationship to THE SAME `ViewController` as its `root`. When `more controller` shows them, for some reason destroy the navigation controller and get its root. So I loose the way how to differentiate selected controller

Comment: What about getting back to objectAtIndex approach? If you have only one controller in More Items, you can try `[tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewController objectAtIndex:0].restorationIdentifier` 
or `[tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewController objectAtIndex:0].view.tag`

Comment: No, because of my image from the question:-(