# UITabBarController dynamic

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have to create a UITabBarController. And items can change if the user is logged or not. Is it possible to change the ta bar items dynamically?

Anybody have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Items?  You can change the view controller array that it manages...is that what you mean?

Comment: I have three items, and I'd like to add "Account" item when user sign in.
I haven't any any how to deal with that...

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
var items: [UITabBarItem]? { get set }
```

or set it with animation :

```
func setItems(_ items: [UITabBarItem]?, 
 animated: Bool)
```

code snippet:

```
let item1 =  UITabBarItem(
        title: "first",
        image: firstImage,
        tag: 1)

let item2 =  UITabBarItem(
        title: "second",
        image: secondImage,
        tag: 2)
yourTabBarVC.tabBar.items = [item1,item2]


let first = FirstViewController()
let second = SecondViewController()

yourTabBarVC.viewControllers = [first, second]
```

Comment: This thing looks good, but I'm a little bit disappointed with obj-c ... how this thing works exactly?

Comment: Just another question, how could I tell the item to use a specific ViewController?

Comment: what do you mean? specific ViewController ?

Comment: see this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521951/how-to-get-the-tag-of-selected-uitabbaritem-in-uitabbarcontroller-for-more-than