# Detecting when tabBar item is pressed when is page

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBar` with 4 tabs.

I want to that a specific function will be called in each `ViewController` of the tab when the `tabBarItem` is pressed twice (like, the user is now on `ProfileVC` and presses on `Profile` item, I want to refresh the view).

How can I detect when the user pressed on the tab that he is in its view now?

Thank you!

Comment: Did u try the tabBar delegate methods ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5455756/1896921)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is do the refreshing inside `viewWillAppear()` method. And the second one is considerably long.

In parent view controller

```
protocol ParentDelegate {
     func refresh()
}

class LandingViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    var delegate: ParentDelegate?
    var selectedItem: UITabBarItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBar.delegate = self
        self.selectedItem = self.tabBar.selectedItem
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "SegueNameForDestinationViewController1" {

            if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? YourDestinationViewController1 {
                self.delegate = vc.self
            }

        } else if segue.identifier == "SegueNameForDestinationViewController2" {

            if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? YourDestinationViewController2 {
                self.delegate = vc.self
            }

        }
    }

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

        if self.selectedItem == item {
            self.delegate?.refresh()
        }
        self.selectedItem = item
    }
}
```

In each tab view controller,

```
class TabViewController: UIViewController, ParentDelegate {

    func refresh() {
        //write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `viewWillAppear()` doesn't being called when re-tap on the same tab item. And about the second option, i'm not using storyboard, how can I do that? thanks!

Comment: The second answer does not require the storyboard. Which part you don't understand?

Comment: segues are just for storyboard, doesn't they?

Comment: Correct! I will modify the answer

Comment: @FS.O5, Instead of `prepareForSegue` method you can use the place where you instantiate the child tab view controller.

Comment: @FS.O5 if this worked consider marking as the answer. Thanks